# How do I use JavaScript to dynamically get dates in the future?

Tags: javascript, date, user-interface, user-experience

I'm trying to re-create this website : https://sbuxdates.com/

I have the html & css complete, but I'm struggling with making it dynamic.

how can I use javascript to display the dates? is there a resource you could share with me that would teach me more? thanks!

Comment: [The Date class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), or one of the libraries [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/recommendations/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add days to JavaScript Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563406/add-days-to-javascript-date)

Comment: View source and look at main.js, it has everything you need.